# How find the file name of an executing AppleScript

Tags: applescript

How do I find the name of an executing AppleScript?

REASON: I want to create a script that changes its behavior based on its filename. Something like:

```
if myname is "Joe" then ACTION1
else if myname is "Frank" then ACTION2
else ACTION3
```

Answer (score 5):

The normal way to get the name is by using "name of me". However applescripts are run by applescript runner so when you use that on a script you get "Applescript Runner" as the name. If you compile your script as an application then "name of me" will work. The only way to get the script name is by getting its path and extracting the name. Something like this would thus work for scripts...

```
getMyName()
tell me to display dialog result

on getMyName()
    set myPath to path to me as text
    if myPath ends with ":" then
        set n to -2
    else
        set n to -1
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set myName to text item n of myPath
    if (myName contains ".") then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        set myName to text 1 thru text item -2 of myName
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return myName
end getMyName
```

Comment: The `path to me` info is great, but note that you can get to the filename more easily with `name of (info for (path to me))`. (`info for` also has a property to report the filename extension, but AppleScript's lack of a string-replacement command means that that's not helpful in this context.) If you want to get away with a single command for removing the extension, see my `do shell script`-based approach.

Comment: I stopped using the "info for" command several versions of applescript ago. Apple had deprecated that command. Of course "info for" is still available but at some point if will go away so just be aware of that if you use it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I did not know that `info for` was deprecated - best to avoid it, then. You can use its replacement as follows: `tell application "System Events" to set myname to get name of (path to me)`. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method that **works for all of the following**:

- `*.scpt` files (compiled AppleScript files; run in AppleScript Editor or with `osascript`)
- `*.applescript` files (uncompiled AppleScript files; run in AppleScript Editor or with `osascript`)
- command-line scripts that directly contain AppleScript (marked as executable and starting with `#!/usr/bin/env osascript`):
- `*.app` files created with AppleScript Editor
- `*.app` files created with Automator that contain AppleScript actions

Note: By contrast, it **does *not* work for** the following:

- macOS services created with Automator that contain AppleScript actions (special `*.workflow` files) - they always report `WorkflowServiceRunner[.xpc]`
- general-purpose `*.workflow` files created with Automator that contain ApplesScript actions and that are run with `automator` - they always reports `Automator Runner[.app]`

Get the name of the running script, including filename extension (`.scpt`, `.app`, or `.applescript`, as the case may be):

```bash
tell application "System Events" to set myname to get name of (path to me)
```

If you want to remove the filename extension with a single command, use the following, `do shell script`-based approach:

```bash
tell application "System Events" to set myname to do shell script "rawName=" & quoted form of (get name of (path to me)) & "; printf '%s' \"${rawName%.*}\""
```

Here's an all-AppleScript alternative that is more verbose (yet concise by AppleScript standards):

```bash
tell application "System Events"
    set myname to name of (path to me)
    set extension to name extension of (path to me)
end tell
if length of extension > 0 then
    # Make sure that `text item delimiters` has its default value here.
    set myname to items 1 through -(2 + (length of extension)) of myname as text
end if
```

Finally, here's a variation: a subroutine that you can call with `set myname to getMyName()`:

```bash
on getMyName()
    local myName, tidSaved
    tell application "System Events"
        set myAlias to path to me -- alias to the file/bundle of the running script
        set myName to name of myAlias -- filename with extension, if any.
        if name extension of myAlias is not "" then -- strip away extension
            set {tidSaved, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, {""}}
            set myName to items 1 through -(2 + (length of (get name extension of myAlias))) of myName as text
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tidSaved
        end if
    end tell
    return myName
end getMyName
```

Comment: The shell script doesn't work if the name contains single quotes or backslashes. You could escape the string with `quoted form of` and add `shopt -u xpg_echo` before the echo.

Comment: @LauriRanta Good points, thank you; I've updated the post. (I had thought single-quoting would be enough, but, as you point out, it's not. While certain backslashes would have been fine, those that together with the following character happen to form an _escape sequence_ cause problems. Note that in theory it should suffice to use `echo -E` instead of `shopt -u xpg_echo`, but inexplicably that misbehaves when run with `do shell script`.)

Comment: echo doesn't have an -E option by default in sh (or POSIX mode).

Comment: Thanks, good to know - I hadn't realized that `do shell script` runs  _all commands in POSIX compatibility mode_.

Comment: @LauriRanta Again, thanks for the POSIX-mode hint. Though it wouldn't be an improvement in this scenario, it occurred to me that in general you can get full bash behavior back simply by using `do shell script "shopt -uo posix; ...`.

Comment: @LauriRanta Found a better solution for the interpretation-as-escape-sequences problem: `cat <<< ...` - never interprets escape sequences, thus no need to set shell option.

Comment: You could also use `printf %s`. `shopt -uo posix; echo '\t'` still prints a literal tab unless you add `-E`. The default shell of do shell script is `/bin/sh`, which is a [version of bash that starts in POSIX mode and emulates some aspects of sh](http://superuser.com/questions/125728/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-and-sh/480885#480885).

Comment: @LauriRanta Good stuff, thanks. Sounds like `printf %s` is the best option, esp. if you don't want a terminating `\n`.

Comment: For path and/or name of an app from a Javascript AppleScript: `app.pathTo(this).toString().split("/").pop();`

Comment: Thanks, @shs; while that works for `*.app` bundles (with a preceding `var app = Application.currentApplication(); app.includeStandardAdditions = true`), it doesn't work for `*.scpt` files and `*.javascript` files - do you know how to make it work there too? Terminology quibble: your code is JXA (JavaScript for Automation), which is an _alternative language_ to AppleScript (both run on OSA, the Open Scripting Architecture).

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to find out the base part of the path is using `name of`:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set p to path to me
    set nam to name of file p as text
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:
set appname to name of current application