# How to execute automator script from its current path?

Tags: bash, automator

I created an automator app that executes simple bash instructions. When I double click on the app file it ends up failing because it runs from `~` and I need it to run from its **current location**. Is there any way to achieve this?

e.g.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know Automator, but why don't you put the complete logic (i.e. `export` and `cd`) into the script and invoke the script using the absolute path? This would at least make debugging easier. BTW, you refer to bash in your question, but select zsh in your automator. Why?

Comment: You can likely adapt this answer to get the name of the script then chop off the filename part and change directory to the other part... https://stackoverflow.com/a/12525531/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell that answer is for applescript, how would it work in automator?

Comment: @user1934428 I can't use the absolute path because I do not know what it will be. This is meant to be executed in other macs

Comment: If you have no information, where the script is located, the only possibility is to request the user of the respective computer to add the location of the script into his PATH.